# Find a specific record from an XML file

Tags: awk, grep, xml

I have an XML with one record each in same xml tags; sample given as below. I need to get the specific record displayed by giving the search pattern as `'4017|95592'`.
Output should be:

```
4017|95592|S|Y|54|14.05|1.97|0|0|0|0|0|2019-07-23 03:25:25|2019-07-23 03:09:04
```

Sample File:

```
<"Record>4017|95592|S|Y|54|14.05|1.97|0|0|0|0|0|2019-07-23 03:25:25|2019-07-23 03:09:04<"/Record><"Record>4017|23071|S|Y|19|5.05|6.62|0|0|0|0|0|2019-07-23 03:25:25|2019-07-23 03:09:04<"/Record>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: That data does not look like XML.

Comment: $ grep -oP '(?<=<Record>).*(?=</Record)' test.xml | grep -F '4017|95592' | awk -F "[><]" '{print $3}'                                                                                                        When the above was used , anytime  it gives only the first record from file, whatever the search pattern be.

Answer (score -1):

Using bash commands

```
sed 's/^.........//g' example.txt | awk -F '\\<' '{print $1}' | grep -w "4017|95592"
```

Comment: Below comments when executed in sequence gave the desired output                                                                                                                                        grep -oP '(?<=<Record>).*(?=</Record)' Test.xml > TEST.txt

Comment: sed -i 's/<Record>/"\n"<Record>/g' TEST.txt

Comment: cat TEST.txt | grep -F '4017|95592' |awk -F "[><]" '/Record/{print $3}'

Comment: Output:4017|95592|S|Y|54|14.05|1.97|0|0|0|0|0|2019-07-23 03:25:25|2019-07-23 03:09:04